# VB.NET - Choose folder by browsing and copy file from application directory

Tags: vb.net, copy, directory

Hello StackOverflow users. I am trying to create an application where you can browse to a folder, press install button and it will copy some files to the directory of your choosing?
I found some example code but
how do i go on with my code from here? Cant figure out how to copy the files. You can see at last in the code i tried to copy files but its not really working, how do i use the function? I want the files to come from the application directory. And copy to the browsed folder.

```
Public Class Installer

Private Sub Installer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked




End Sub




Private Sub BrowseButton_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseButton.Click
    ' Declare a variable named theFolderBrowser of type FolderBrowserDialog.
    Dim theFolderBrowser As New FolderBrowserDialog

    ' Set theFolderBrowser object's Description property to
    '   give the user instructions.
    theFolderBrowser.Description = "Please browse to your GTAIV directory."

    ' Set theFolderBrowser object's ShowNewFolder property to false when
    '   the a FolderBrowserDialog is to be used only for selecting an existing folder.
    theFolderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = False

    ' Optionally set the RootFolder and SelectedPath properties to
    '   control which folder will be selected when browsing begings
    '   and to make it the selected folder.
    ' For this example start browsing in the Desktop folder.
    theFolderBrowser.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
    ' Default theFolderBrowserDialog object's SelectedPath property to the path to the Desktop folder.
    theFolderBrowser.SelectedPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop

    ' If the user clicks theFolderBrowser's OK button..
    If theFolderBrowser.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Set the FolderChoiceTextBox's Text to theFolderBrowserDialog's
        '    SelectedPath property.
        Me.FolderTextBox.Text = theFolderBrowser.SelectedPath

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles InstallButton.Click

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, theFolderBrowser.SelectedPath)


End Sub
End Class
```

- SnoX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this line of code

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath,  _
                                theFolderBrowser.SelectedPath)
```

the `theFolderBrowser` object cannot be referenced because it was a local variable inside another method. However, before exiting, you have copied the selected path into a textbox. You could use that textbox as destination of your copy

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath,  _
                                     Me.FolderTextBox.Text )
```

And also keep in mind that CopyFile copies only one file, if you intend to copy an entire folder you need the CopyDirectory method. There is another important detail in this method:

If your files exist in the destination directory and you don't use the overload with the overwrite flag you will get an exception

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath,  _
                                     Me.FolderTextBox.Text, True )
```